# Including a variable on legend label with special characters in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Here is part of my code and I would like to have some variables in the legend:

```
c1 = raw_input("enter c1: ")
c2 = raw_input("c2: ")

mainax.plot(x, y, label=r"power law, $n$ =" + c1 + "$\times$ 10$^" + c2 + "cm$^{-3}$")
```

It should be equivalent to the following if I remove the variables:

```
mainax.plot(x, y, label=r"power law, $n$ = 2.1 $\times$ 10$^{12}$ cm$^{-3}$")
```

What I want at the end should be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.format` string formatting options in order to get the label that you want. Here you must make sure that you have the right number of curly braces as the `.format` takes up one of them:

```
c1 = "2.1"
c2 = "12"
label = r'power law, $n$ = {} $\times$ 10$^{{{}}}$ cm$^{{-3}}$'.format(c1, c2)

plt.plot([1,2], [1,2], label=label)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: DavidG Thanks for the answer.